# How to refactor this JQuery code so that it follows the DRY principle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

See.  I have the following html `<ul>-<li>` lists here.

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="active"><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li> 
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="about-us">About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Who we are?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What we stand for?</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="campaigns">Campaigns<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="donate">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I have the following jquery code

```
$("#about-us").click(function(){
   $("ul.nav").children("li").children("a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
   $(this).css("background-color","#47F514");
});

$("#campaigns").click(function(){
   $("ul.nav").children("li").children("a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
   $(this).css("background-color","#F2720A");
});

$("#news").click(function(){
   $("ul.nav").children("li").children("a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
   $(this).css("background-color","#0A76F2");
});

$("#donate").click(function(){
   $("ul.nav").children("li").children("a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
   $(this).css("background-color","#F7A116");
});
```

I can see that line `$("ul.nav").children("li").children("a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E")` is repeated in many lines. So surely I can take this out and put a new function in each click events to make this same calls this many times.

What should I do to refactor this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
var colors_array_by_id = { "about-us" : "#47F514", "campaigns" : "#F2720A", "news" : "#0A76F2", "donate" : "#F7A116" };
$("#about-us, #campaigns, #news, #donate").click(function(){
   $("ul.nav > li > a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
   $(this).css("background-color", colors_array_by_id[$(this).attr('id')]);
});
```

The only thing that changes is the color depending of the clicked element. So, I created here an associative array containing id-color couples.

Comment: +1. `$("ul.nav > li > a").click(...` would save having to list out the ids. (And `$("ul.nav > li > a")` could be cached for use inside the function.)

Comment: @nnnnnn How to "save having to list out the ids"?

Comment: @wared - Use `"ul.nav > li > a"` instead of `"#about-us, #campaigns, #news, #donate"`. You would still use the `colors_array_by_id` with the ids listed, but then if another menu item was added its id would only need to be added to one place in the JS.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input.  They're great ideas!  I'll give them  a go when I get the chance.  It's really awesome how you can just write a few lines of code to achieve the same results.  May even improve the performance on the browser too.

Comment: It might be even better to something like `$('ul.nav').on('click', 'li > a', function () { ... })`, this way you would have only one listener which is a bit cleaner then adding a separate listener to each link.

Comment: Thanks fellas.  All of your suggestions above all worked! I'm very pleased. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it -

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="active"><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li> 
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navLinks" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bgcolor="#47F514" id="about-us">About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Who we are?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What we stand for?</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navLinks" data-toggle="dropdown"  data-bgcolor="#F2720A"  id="campaigns">Campaigns<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="news" class="navLinks" data-bgcolor="#0A76F2" >News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="donate" class="navLinks" data-bgcolor="#F7A116" >Donate</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've added a data attribute to the links called data-bgcolor which has the color value. Next I attach a single click handler to all the links.

```
$("#about-us, #campaigns, #news, #donate").click(function(){
   $("ul.nav").children("li").children("a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
   $(this).css("background-color", $(this).attr("data-bgcolor"));
});
```

Comment: If you changed it to `$("ul.nav > li > a").click(...` the JS wouldn't need to know about any of the ids at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this,

In css,

```
.myClass{ background-color: #OEOEOE;}
```

on load,

```
var elm = $("ul.nav").children("li").children("a");
```

and then,

```
$("#about-us, #campaigns, #news, #donate").click(function(){
   $this = $(this);

   elm.addClass("myClass");
   $this.css("background-color", $this.data("bgcolor"));
});
```

You can use the `.data()` instead of `.attr()`.